# How to add column names of a matrix when using xmlNode in R?

Tags: xml, r

I want to export my data to XML and I'm not sure how to add the column names of the matrix without writing its names.
I have a matrix named "results"  with 2 columns: time, p_value
How can I add the columns names to the xmlNode?
I'm using XML package:

> xmlNode(results)
>       <2013-10-27 13:00:00/>
>       <0.99/>

I want it to look like that:

```
<time>2013-10-27 13:00:00</time>
<p_value>0.99</p_value>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about `XML` package?

Comment: I'm using xmlNode from XML package, but I don't get the names of the columns and I didn't find how to do that.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was not evident from your question. You may want to edit the question to underline you know how to export, but have a problem with specifying tags. In that case, you are more likely to get more attention.

Comment: I made the changes. Thank you.

Comment: Is it a matrix or a data frame? You seem to have dates and numbers in it, so I'm guessing its a data frame. Yes this does make a difference. Give us a few lines of code that constructs a data frame that shows us the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are creating an XML document rather than just a fragment:

```
> results=data.frame(time=date(),p_value=0.99,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then start a new XML tree and add names nodes to it:

```
> z = xmlTree("mydata")
Warning message:
In xmlRoot.XMLInternalDocument(currentNodes[[1]]) : empty XML document
> z$addNode("time",results$time)
> z$addNode("p_value",results$p_value)
```

Then the XML looks like:

```
> cat(xml(z))
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<mydata>
  <time>Wed Jan 29 08:24:18 2014</time>
  <p_value>0.99</p_value>
</mydata>
```

See the help for `xmlTree` for more.

If you want to create a single node with your data in, you have to wrap it in a higher level XML node - you can't just have an XML structure of two things like that. Hence:

```
> xmlNode("data",.children=lapply(names(results),function(n){xmlNode(n,results[[n]])}))
<data>
 <time>Wed Jan 29 08:24:18 2014</time>
 <p_value>0.99</p_value>
</data>
```

This creates a new node called `data` and then loops over the results data frame, creating single new nodes for each element with the right name and value and adding them as children to the `data` node.

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful. I tried to run it on a data frame with a few rows and got the results mixed:                                                                        <data>
     <split_time>2013-10-27 13:00:002013-10-27 13:00:00</split_time>
     <split_type>running_totaldeltas</split_type>
     <split_level>BrowserBrowser</split_level>
     <p>0.9999049356582450.798653468698788</p>
</data>   How can I separate the results?

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman- In the last comment I showed results of the last code you wrote for two rows. How can I separate the results so each row will have a separated node?

Comment: Please edit your question to better reflect your data, including examples.

Comment: @Spacedman- I'm trying to write the comment in the format I wrote my question and don't manage to do that. It seems that it won't read my code line when I uses  `code in backticks`. can I get your email and send to you my question?

Comment: There should be an 'edit' link up by your question. Use that, make your question better. If you don't have an edit link then it might be because you haven't earnt enough rep points yet. Start a new question?

Comment: Are you sure? Under the tags below your original question. Should be some text links like 'share', and 'edit'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429719/how-to-get-a-separated-xml-format-for-each-row-in-a-data-frame