# How to get a separated XML format for each row in a data frame?

Tags: xml, r

I want to export my data frame to XML format. In the data frame- "results" I have two columns and two rows.
I use this code:

```
xmlNode("data",.children=lapply(names(results),function(n){xmlNode(n,results[[n]])}))
```

and I get mixed results:

```
<data> <time>2013-10-27 13:00:002013-10-27 13:00:00</time>
<p_value>0.990.79</p_value> </data>`
```

The two rows entered to the same XML node.
I will have more than 2 rows so I want to be able to get separated XML format for each row, like that:

```
<data> 
<time>2013-10-27 13:00:00</time>
<p_value>0.99</p_value>
</data>
```

And the next row will look like that:

```
<data> 
<time>2013-10-27 13:00:00</time>
<p_value>0.79</p_value>
</data
```

My question is how to separate the rows in XML format?

Comment: You're not thinking in 'Nodes'. Each tagged thing is a node. So you need a node for your whole data frame, containing nodes for each row, containing a node for each element. If you read `help(addNode)` you should see an example of how to create something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with some dummy data:

```
dt <- data.frame( x = 1:10, y = LETTERS[1:10] )
```

In your example you are applying over the data.frame columns (using `lapply`) although you explain, that you'd rather want to apply over rows. Then it would look like this:

```
xmlNode( "data", .children = apply(
  dt, 1, function(n){
    xmlNode( "row", 
      xmlNode( names(dt)[1], n[1] ),
      xmlNode( names(dt)[2], n[2] )
    )
  }
))   

<data>
 <row>
  <x> 1</x>
  <y>A</y>
 </row>
 <row>
  <x> 2</x>
  <y>B</y>
...
```

### Generic solution

And if you are looking for a more general solution, to convert an arbitrary `data.frame` to an xml node, you could use this solution:

```
library(plyr)
xmlNode( "data", .children =
  alply( results, 1, function(row)
    xmlNode( "row", 1, .children = alply( row , 2, function(cell) xmlNode( names(cell), cell ) ) )
  )
)
```