# Generate good to parse xml trees from data frames in R

Tags: xml, r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame df:

```
df<-data.frame(c("A","B","C","D"), c(1,2,3,10),c(1.0,2.5,3.14,-4))
names(df)<-c("test","foo","bar")
```

One method (beside the one presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429719/how-to-get-a-separated-xml-format-for-each-row-in-a-data-frame)) is to apply lapply:

```
xmlNode("dataframe",.children=lapply(names(df),function(n){xmlNode(n,df[[n]])}))
```

As mentioned in the previously referred link the rows do not seem to be separated. Technically, though, this does not seem to be true. When I make a small SApply:

```
xmlSApply(xmlNode("dataframe",.children=lapply(names(df),function(n){xmlNode(n,df[[n]])}))[[1]], xmlValue)
```

I get all values in the respective column perfectly separated:

```
    text
[1,] "A" 
[2,] "B" 
[3,] "C" 
[4,] "D"
```

This would enable me to plot the data etc. However, when I save the xml structure and re-load it the separation between the elements is gone.

My questions are:

1.) Is via the way described here a way to save the data in such a manner that I can separate the elements afterwards (as I can do when the xml tree is not yet written to the hard drive)?

2.) If that cannot be done: How can I parse efficiently per column when I use the generic method by Beaterfield ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21433323/2780196))?

Answer (score 0):

`plyr` is not required and just attack this in a straightforward manner vs try to use fancy `apply` constructs (it's just a cpl more lines):

```
library(XML)

dat <- data.frame(test=c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                  foo=c(1, 2, 3, 10),
                  bar=c(1.0, 2.5, 3.14,- 4))

dat

##   test foo   bar
## 1    A   1  1.00
## 2    B   2  2.50
## 3    C   3  3.14
## 4    D  10 -4.00

# make a new XML doc
doc <- newXMLDoc()

# add a root node
root <- newXMLNode("datframe", doc=doc)

# build rows/cols
for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  row <- newXMLNode("row", parent=root)
  for (col in names(dat)) {
    newXMLNode(col, dat[i, col], parent=row)
  }
}

# verify it worked
xmlToDataFrame(doc)

##   test foo  bar
## 1    A   1    1
## 2    B   2  2.5
## 3    C   3 3.14
## 4    D  10   -4

# write it out to a file
saveXML(doc, "dataframe.xml")

## [1] "dataframe.xml"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! How would I parse the "foo" and the "bar"-values in doc (if I'd like to plot bar over foo)?

Comment: just convert the columns with  `as.numeric` as you would a standard data.frame.

Comment: Ok, so your approach would be to reconvert the whole xml-tree and work with it. That I do understand, my question in the comments was how I would parse the xml-structure to get to the foo- and bar-columns.

Comment: No, I would use the data frame as normal. You're the one who needed it converted to XML. I just showed that the example conversion worked.